# Cardview inside fragment

Tags: java, android-fragments

Im trying to put cards in one of the fragment but I got this error: There is no applicable constuctor to '(com.sample.app.FragmentOne)'. By the way Im using AIDE IDE.

The error is the *(this)* here:

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
```

**FragmentOne.java**

```
package com.sample.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.sample.app.MainActivity;
import com.sample.app.R;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment One");

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new CardAdapter();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return view;
}

}
```

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I changed this

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
```

Into

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 1):

Change that `this` to `getActivity()`
For Activity, use something like `(MainActivity.this);`
For Fragments, use `getActivity();` or `requirActivity();`